# Bootstrap dropdown not opening when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a dropdown using Bootstrap with several options but when I click the button nothing comes down to select the option. Not sure what is going on.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>A Basic HTML5 Template</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="SelectOS" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Select option...</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="SelectOS">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Linux</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Windows</a>
                </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data-bs-toggle` attribute instead of the `data-toggle` attribute.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>A Basic HTML5 Template</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Atwg2Pkwv9vp0ygtn1JAojH0nYbwNJLPhwyoVbhoPwBhjQPR5VtM2+xf0Uwh9KtT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="SelectOS" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Select option...</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="SelectOS">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Linux</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mac</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Windows</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```